# WCF - possible to call a wcf service from the command line with parameters?

Tags: wcf, iis

Is it possible to call an IIS hosted wcf service from the command line and pass through parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Write a console application that calls the WCF service, and then call the console application from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what binding your WCF service uses but with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) you can post pretty much everything to a given url.